# ggplot2: Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type labelled

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and also to SO. Currently I have to write an assignment and so far, R seems a lot like fun! We're analysing data from the European Social Survey, focusing on GB. I simply want to plot the distribution of the variable `income` (1 to 10).

The code I use is:

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(GB, aes(x=income)) +
    geom_bar(width = .5, fill = "tomato3", na.rm = TRUE)
    labs(title="Income Distribution",
    caption = "Source: ESS7 (2014)")
```

This is just one way I tried it. The error code "*Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type labelled. Defaulting to continuous.*" keeps coming. Since I'm writing the assignment in R Markdown, I'd love to get rid of it.

### Data sample

```
> dput(dplyr::select(head(GB, 20), income))
    structure(list(income = structure(c(4, 2, 2, 6, 1, 5, 10, 2, 
    6, 7, 7, NA, NA, 4, 8, NA, 3, 6, 10, 1), labels = c(`J - 1st
    decile` = 1, `R - 2nd decile` = 2, `C - 3rd decile` = 3,
    `M - 4th decile` = 4, `F - 5th decile` = 5, `S - 6th decile` = 6,
    `K - 7th decile` = 7, `P - 8th decile` = 8, `D - 9th decile` = 9,
    `H - 10th decile` = 10, Refusal = 77, `Don't know` = 88,
    `No answer` = 99), class = "labelled")), row.names = c(NA, -20L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Can anyone help? :)

Edit: I added `factor` to the code - the error message has vanished, but the NA values are included in the bar plot, even though I wrote `na.rm=TRUE`. What could be wrong? Code used:

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(GB, aes(x=factor(income))) +
geom_bar(width = .5, fill="tomato3", na.rm = TRUE) +
labs(title="Verteilung des Haushaltseinkommens",
    caption = "Quelle: ESS7 (2014)")
```

[image: NA]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It likely has something to do with how your data is stored in your data frame but you didn't include any details about that.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(GB)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(GB, 20))`.

Comment: Hi, I used the code `dput(head(GB,10))`, but it's a lot of text, since all values of the variables are explained. Is it enough if I post you `dput(head(GB$income,10))`?

Comment: you can turn warnings off in rmarkdown with the chunk option `warning = FALSE` - but obviously it is better to fix the underlying problem.

Comment: `dput(dplyr::select(head(GB, 20), income))` would be better - keeps it in a dataframe

Comment: I included the data sample above after running `dput(dplyr::select(head(GB, 20), income))`

Comment: How are you reading this data in? I know that if you read in data from SPSS or Stata using `haven`, you get labelled vectors, which you might want to convert to `factor`s.

Comment: Hi Marius, the data (ESS7e02_1.dta) was read in with the library `haven`, then filtered with the code `Grossbritannien <- filter(ESS7e02_1, cntry == "GB")`. As we only have to look at 9 variables out of more than 500 or so, we created a new object (GB) using `dplyr`: `GB <- dplyr::select(Grossbritannien, government, father_educ, local, gender, height, weight, age, education, income)`.

Comment: I have tried converting the variable `income` into a factor with `as.factor(GB2$income)`. Then I omitted the NAs (77, 88, 99) by writing `GB2$income[GB2$income > 10] <- NA` which has worked. After trying to run the ggplot command again, the bar chart is presented, but I still get the error message

Comment: If you are using haven, try `as_factor(GB)` (note underscore) to turn labeled vectors into factors (be sure to save the result to a new variable)